# Magento: overriding Adminhtml template causes memory limit exhaustion

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to override a phtml file within Magento's admin area. Specifically, the file I'm trying to override is: **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml**

In **app/code/local/CompanyName/Website/etc/config.xml**, I have:

```
<rewrite>
    <catalog_form_renderer_fieldset_element>CompanyName_Website_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element</catalog_form_renderer_fieldset_element>
</rewrite>
```

The overriding block PHP file I have placed into **app/code/local/CompanyName/Website/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Form/Renderer/Fieldset/Element.php**. This file contains:

```
<?php

class CompanyName_Website_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setTemplate('catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml');
    }
}
```

Finally, the overriding template file is at **app/design/frontend/enterprise/CompanyName/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml** and contains the actual template I'm overriding.

I get a white screen and in the log there's this error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 227543041 bytes) in /var/www/html/gold/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 569`

Any thoughts? Am I extending the right class? Files placed correctly? Etc. There are other `<rewrite>` blocks inside the same config.xml file which work just fine so I must be making a mistake!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is odd for a couple of reasons.

It seems that you are merely interested in changing the template of this block.  Why not just override its default template 'widget/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml'?

Are you sure you don't have something like print_r($someObject->getData()); somewhere in your constructor or template?

Further Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element::_construct() merely sets the template file, so probably no reason to call parent::_construct().

Have you set some error_log()'s around in your constructor and template file to make sure they are being called? What is the full path to that template? Namely is it something like /app/design/adminhtml/default/default...? or /app/design/adminhtml/company/...? If the later, I assume you have the suitable config in place to allow for adminhtml template override?

What is going on in line 569 of /lib/Varien/Object.php?  (mine must be a different version because that line is in a comment and its around stuff that doesn't seem relevant)

---

EDIT:
To override an adminhtml template.  Add this to the < config > node in /app/etc/local.xml

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>companyname</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Now make a folder in /app/design/adminhtml/default/ named 'companyname' and put 'template', 'layout' etc. folders inside it as you would any theme. e.g. /app/design/adminhtml/default/companyname/template/widget/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml for your case.

Comment: It was my understanding that you couldn't simply override adminhtml templates and that you had to create a module to do this. Is this incorrect? Searching Google for "magento override adminhtml template" brings up very mixed results, none of which are clear. There's even this convoluted-seeming approach by Inchoo, [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-override-magento-admin-view-template-files-quick-and-dirty-way/). 

Is there an easier way?

Comment: You certainly can! (at least the version I'm on...)  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That does work (although I changed `</store>` to `</stores>`). Is there any way to make it "truly modular": that is, to edit the /etc/config.xml file within the module folder itself, rather than the global app/etc/config.xml file?

Comment: It's worth noting that the community `Find_Feed` module which shipped with CE <= 1.6 / EE <= 1.11 contained the `stores/admin/design` configuration nodes described in this solution. Therefore, it would be necessary to specify `stores/admin/design/package/theme/template` in order to use the full fallback mechanism & not break the `Find_Feed` module.

Comment: Good catch, I typed the XML by hand, and obviously messed up the last closing tag.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'break the Find_Feed' module, I've been using this override method for a while now.  On 1.12.0.2 I don't have any modules starting with 'F', and greping for 'Find_Feed' doesn't come back with anything either.

Comment: @benmarks could you please go into some detail about what you mean, and how you'd modify the above solution to maintain compatibility with the Find_Feed module?

Comment: @WackGet - Just need to change the xpath to the theme to be as I wrote, everything else Jared said should work.